# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, axis, talend

I have deployed a web service over server (Tomcat 9). but when I call it in browser, I am getting this error:

> "HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception"

[image: Click here to see Error]

How to resolve it?

Details:

I have created a job in Talend open studio. 
Then I build that job as a Axis web service (`.war`) and deployed it over Tomcat server. I followed this tutorial link:

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforDataIntegrationUserGuide62EN/5.2.2+How+to+build+Jobs?_ga=1.142016306.1890479853.1478596067

Now after deployment I am facing the above mentioned error.
What should I do?

Comment: The class `org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc` cannot be found, check that your webapp has the relevant axis jars .

Comment: Thanks Berger.  I added the relevant jars and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the relevant jar files solves the issue.

Files:

1> axis.jar

2> wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar